# 2002 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo turn signals

Tags: turn-signal

I bought a 2002 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo. Noticed the turn signals sometimes works & then just stop for a few days. I replaced the relay and it did not help. Nothing else is affected but the turn signals.  could it be the multifunction switch? and is this easy to replace? any other ideas? Thanks so much for any help

Comment: When the turn signals stop working, check to see if the hazzard flashers do.  Thisinformation will go a long way in troubleshooting a rather broad problem.

Comment: SteveRacer....thanks for responding.  Yes, they do still  work.... everything else works fine.  I have changed and/or tested all fuses....  I alreadyknow labor to find the issue will cost me $150...then the part, if it is the switch....or I can get one at Autozone for about $75..... knew I should have been a mechanic instead of an RN *smile

Comment: If you are able to recreate the problem, or test when you know it is not working, test if there is voltage going into the switch.  If there is, test for voltage coming out of the switch when moved to different positions.  If there is no voltage coming in, then it is a fuse or broken wire.  If it is coming in, but not out, its a bad switch.  If you see it going out, follow it until you find the voltage stop.  A schematic and test light will be very useful here.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an entire solution, but your test of the hazard lamps leads me to believe the problem is within the following diagram... and most likely, from the view of my sofa, the multifucntion switch "stalk".  @rpmerf's comment suggestion is the way to pursue evaluation of this suspect switch.  I would stil double-check fuse #20, as a failure here (even burned or loose contacts with a good fuse) would create this same condition.  Hazards will run always (through fuse #4), but turn signals only with a key in "run" position.

[image]